# Substitution operator in Perl

Tags: perl, string-substitution

I am new to perl. I have the following substitution expression:

```
$tmp =~ s:/x/y/z::;
```

I have searched a lot for it but couldn't find a similar expression. 
What does it mean?

Comment: `s|/x/y/z||` or `s!/x/y/z!!` would be more common variant.

Comment: Using `|` is pretty rare, actually , since `|` is quite often needed in patterns. `s{}{}` is probably the second most common after `s///`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use non-whitespace any character as a delimiter; here, instead of the most common `/` (`s/foo/bar/`), the delimiter is `:` (s:foo:bar:), because what you are substituting has slash characters and if you used a slash delimiter, you'd have to escape them (`s/\/x\/y\/z//`) which many people consider ugly.

So your expression is simply removing the first `/x/y/z` from `$tmp`.

Comment: @F.Hauri Thanks. I'm assuming what the OP is asking about is the change of delimiter, not the general use of `=~`.  If I'm wrong, I will add more about that.

Answer (score 3):

That means: replace `/x/y/z` with nothing.

For exmaple: If you have a strng like `/a/b/x/y/z` the result will be `/a/b`